# What goes wrong with this alternate proof of Dirichlet's Theorem?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory

I had an idea for an alternate proof of Dirichlet's theorem, but something goes wrong.  Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression says that for $ m,a \in \mathbb{N} $ which are relatively prime, there are infinitely many primes $ q \equiv a \pmod{m} $.  Here is an abbreviated version.  If anyone is curious about more details I am more than glad to provide them.

Define an action $ \beta $ of $ \mu_{m} $ on $ \mathbb{A}^{n}_{k} $ as follows.  If $ \mu_{m} \cong \operatorname{Spec}(k[t]_{t}/ \langle t^{m}-1 \rangle) $ as a scheme, and $ p_{i} $ is the $ i $-th prime natural number, then the co-action $ \beta^{\sharp} $ is the one below:
\begin{equation*}
\beta^{\sharp}(x_{i}) = \overline{t}^{p_{i}-a}x_{i}.
\end{equation*}
This defines an action of $ \mu_{m} $ on $ \mathbb{A}^{n}_{k} $ (If someone needs the details, I can provide them).  If $ \mathbb{A}^{n}_{k} \cong \operatorname{Spec}(\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbf{V}^{\ast})) $, then $ \dim_{k}\left(\left(\mathbf{V}^{\ast}\right)^{\mu_{m}}\right) $ is equal to the number of primes $ q \in \{2,3,5,p_{4},\dots,p_{n}\} $ such that $ q \equiv a \pmod{m} $ (this is one of the details that I am abbreviating).

The idea is then to assume that for $ n>N $ that $ \dim_{k}\left(\left(\mathbf{V}^{\ast}\right)^{\mu_{m}} \right) $ is equal to $ L $ and find a contradiction using asymptotic estimates and theorems of Derksen and Kemper.  Recall that a set of primary invariants is a homogeneous, set of parameters $ \{f_{1}(X),\dots,f_{n}(X)\} $ for the ring $ k[X]^{\mu_{m}} $.  If $ A $ is the ring $ k[f_{1}(X),\dots,f_{n}(X)] $, then a set of secondary invariants is a set $ \{g_{1}(X),\dots,g_{M}(X)\} $ such that $ k[X]^{\mu_{m}} = \oplus_{i=1}^{M} A g_{i}(X) $.  If $ \{f_{1}(X),\dots,f_{n}(X)\} $ is a set of primary invariants of degrees $ d_{1},\dots,d_{n} $ respectively, for a faithful, linear, representation $ \beta: \mu_{m} \to \operatorname{GL}(\mathbf{V}) $, and $ \{g_{1}(X),\dots,g_{M}(X)\} $ is a minimal set of secondary invariants, then $ M \ge (d_{1} \cdots d_{n})/\operatorname{ord}(\mu_{m}) $.

If $ B_{d} $ is the $ d $-th graded part of a graded ring $ B $, then by Noether's theorem $ k[X]^{\mu_{m}} $ is generated by elements of order $ 0 \le i \le m-1 $.  As a result $ M \le \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \dim_{k} (k[X]^{\mu_{m}}_{i}) $.  Since $ k[X]^{\mu_{m}}_{i} \subseteq k[X]_{i} $, we have that
\begin{align*}
M & \le \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \dim_{k}(k[X]^{\mu_{m}}_{i}) \\
& \le \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \dim_{k}(k[X]_{i}) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \binom{n-1+i}{i}.
\end{align*}
This last quantity is $ O(n^{m}) $.  On the other hand, if our assumption is in place, we may choose a set of primary invariants $ \{f_{1}(X),\dots,f_{n}(X)\} $ such that $ f_{1}(X),\dots,f_{L}(X) $ are linear polynomials spanning $ (\mathbf{V}^{\ast})^{\mu_{m}} $ while $ \deg(f_{i}(X)) \ge 2 $ for $ L+1 \le i \le n $.  So
\begin{align*}
M & \ge (d_{1}\cdots d_{n})/m\\
&= (d_{L+1}\cdots d_{n})/m \\
&\ge 2^{n-L-1}/m.
\end{align*}
This last part is $ O(2^{n}) $.  Putting these two parts together, we find that
\begin{align*}
O(n^{m}) & = \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \binom{n-1+i}{i} \\
& \ge M \\
& \ge (d_{1}\cdots d_{n})/m\\
&= 2^{n-L-1}/m \\
&= O(2^{n}).
\end{align*}
This is a contradiction which means that $ \dim_{k}\left(\left(\mathbf{V}^{\ast}\right)^{\mu_{m}} \right) $ cannot be fixed as $ n $ increases.  This implies that there are infinitely many primes $ q \equiv a \pmod{m} $.

However, there is a drastic problem.  The proof seems to work even if $ m $ and $ a $ are not relatively prime!  I suspect that the problem is that in certain cases the desired representation is not faithful.  However, I cannot figure out what is the problem.  I typically work with non-reductive groups, and so this scenario is a little foreign.  If you know what goes wrong and can tell me what is the problem, I will be grateful.

Update: It appears that the upper bound is flawed.  Thank you @SashaP and @alpoge for your help.

Comment: Why is $M$ bounded from above by this sum of dimensions? Secondary invariants are products of these low-degree elements so the space of secondary invariants potentially has dimension that is exponential in the dimension of the generating space, cohering with your lower bound.  Imagine that $\mu_m$ acts on $\mathbb{A}^n$ scaling each coordinate by $t$. Then there are $n$ primary invariants of degree $m$, but a choice for the set of secondary invariants is $x_1^{i_1}\dots x_n^{i_n}$ with all $i_k<m$ and $\sum i_k$ divisible by $m$, so e.g. for $m=2$ the number of these is $2^{n-1}$.

Comment: SashaP’s comment is completely correct: Noether’s bound refers to generators *as a $k$-algebra*, your secondary invariants are to generate as an $A$-*module*. I just wanted to point out that because your argument never actually uses the word “prime” (and indeed you could have defined the $\mu_m$ action for any set of integers $p_i$) the argument structure is: assume Dirichlet’s theorem is false, here is a contradiction in mathematics which is in fact unrelated to the assumption, therefore Dirichlet’s theorem is true. So it had to be flawed for a more basic reason!

Comment: @SashaP Noether's bound says that $ k[X]^{\mu_{m}} $ is generated by homogeneous parts of degrees between zero and $ m-1 $.  As a result, one can choose the primary invariants from homogeneous parts of degrees between zero and $ m-1 $.  Because $ k[X]^{\mu_{m}} $ is a finitely generated $ A $ module, where $ A = k[f_{1}(X),\dots,f_{n}(X)] $, then $ g_{1}(X),\dots,g_{M}(X) $ is a set of $ A $ module generators.  One may also choose these generators from homogeneous parts of degrees between zero and $ m-1 $.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @alpoge I recognize that the argument is wrong.  What you say about the argument structure is true.  However, if we know why the argument is wrong, then we may be able to assign other conditions that lead to a correct argument in this case and possibly to similar correct arguments in other cases.

Comment: @schemer I'm not sure how Noether's bound implies this -- in the example I mentioned above it's impossible to choose primary or secondary invariants from degree $\leq m-1$ components. In fact, in those components only constant functions are invariant.

Comment: @SashaP Thank you Sasha.  I made a necessary edit.  The order of the group of all (not necessarily primitive) $ m $-th roots of unity is $ m $ and not $ m-1 $.  I believe that it is possible to choose primary and secondary invariants of degrees less than or equal to $ m $.

Comment: @schemer This is not the case in the very same example though: there are plenty of invariant elements (such as $x_1^ix_2^jx_3^k$ with $i+j+k=2m$ and $1\leq i, j, k\leq m-1$) that cannot be expressed using only invariants of degrees $\leq m$.